# Python GATT Server to stream BLE through to Windows

Tags: python, windows, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

There are BlueZ linux pygatt libraries which work great on OSX and linux to stream the Nordic BLE UART examples through to a machine from a Nordic SoC chip, however I can't find any support for doing the same thing in windows?

How would you stream BLE UART data(Nordic's UART example) from a device through to  a windows machine? Is there any python gatt library that doesn't depend on BlueZ that can run on windows?

Answer (score -1):

**Solution 1: Bleak**

[bleak](https://github.com/hbldh/bleak) is using a wrapper to `Python for .NET` to make BLE work with Python without Bluez. It's in early stage and there is little to no documentation.

**Solution 2: pygatt**

[pygatt](https://github.com/peplin/pygatt) supports BLE with BGAPIBackend, but you need a Bluegiga compatible Bluetooth dongle (e.g. BLED112)